# State change listener for MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In this diagram are lot of [states](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram):

[image: MediaPlayer states]

but with standard listener I can listen just some basic states.

So is possible to listen every states changes for MediaPlayer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately I found no way of doing this other than surrounding the MediaPlayer with a custom state machine container.

Added ...

You could create a container that is a singleton and defines it's own states. And the only interaction with the MediaPlayer is done through this container. All other classes need to access the API of the container.

Below is a simple outline:

```
public class MyContainer implements OnBufferingUpdateListener, 
                                            OnCompletionListener, 
                                            OnErrorListener,  
                                            OnInfoListener, 
                                            OnPreparedListener 
{
    static enum MP_STATES
    {
        MPS_IDLE,
        MPS_INITIALIZED,
        MPS_PREPARING,
        MPS_PREPARED,
        MPS_STARTED,
        MPS_STOPPED,
        MPS_PAUSED,
        MPS_PLAYBACK_COMPLETED,
        MPS_ERROR,
        MPS_END,
    }

    private static MyContainer s_mpm = null;
    private MP_STATES m_eState;
    private MediaPlayer m_mp;

    public static MyContainer get()
    {
        if (null == s_mpm)
        {
            s_mpm = new MyContainer();          
        }
        return s_mpm;
    }

    private MyContainer()
    {       
        m_mp = new MediaPlayer();
        m_mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        m_mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        m_mp.setOnErrorListener(this);
        m_mp.setOnInfoListener(this);
        m_mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);

        m_eState = MP_STATES.MPS_IDLE;
    }

    public MP_STATES getState()
    {
        return m_eState;
    }

    public void setUrl(String szUrl)
    {
        bringToIdleState();

        try {
            m_mp.setDataSource(szUrl);
            m_eState = MP_STATES.MPS_INITIALIZED;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        m_mp.prepareAsync();
        m_eState = MP_STATES.MPS_PREPARING;
    }

    public void play()
    {
        switch (m_eState)
        {
            case MPS_PREPARED:
            case MPS_PAUSED:
                m_mp.start();
                m_eState = MP_STATES.MPS_STARTED;
                break;
            default:
                // !! throw exception
        }       
    }

    public void pause()
    {
        switch (m_eState)
        {
            case MPS_STARTED:
                m_mp.pause();
                m_eState = MP_STATES.MPS_PAUSED;
                break;
            default:
                // !! throw exception
        }       
    }

    public void release() 
    {
        m_mp.release();
        m_mp = null;
    }

    private void bringToIdleState()
    {
        // reset() should bring MP to IDLE
        m_mp.reset();
        m_eState = MP_STATES.MPS_IDLE;      
    }   

    // ** Callbacks

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) 
    {
        m_eState = MP_STATES.MPS_PREPARED;    
        m_mp.start();
        m_eState = MP_STATES.MPS_STARTED;           
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) 
    {
        m_eState = MP_STATES.MPS_IDLE;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
    {
          // play the next song
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) 
    {
    }

}
```

}

Comment: I added an example to the post. fyi, even if the MP state was public, I would still surround the MP with such a container just to abstract and limit access to the MP.

Comment: Nice job. Work smoothly